# Partition offset at 63 or 64?

Tags: partition, openbsd, fdisk

I did not wish to use the entire SSD for OpenBSD 5.5. (The SSD is new and pre-formatted with MSDOS using Gparted)

During installation and at the fdisk stage, I chose Partition #: 0 to install OpenBSD (I changed the Partition ID to a6). I plan to install other Unix-like OS in Partition #: 1 or 2.

When prompted for partition offset (the default is 0), I entered 64 instead of 63 (I read somewhere on the internet that for SSDs, the offset should begin at 64). Is that correct?

Below are additional details about the disk geometry of my SSD:

[image: disk geometry]

The installation proceeded smoothly without a hitch.

Upon rebooting my machine, the last few lines were the error messages:

```
root on sd0a swap on sd0b dump on sd0b
panic: root filesystem has size 0
Stopped at Debugger+0x5 : leave
Run at least 'trace' AND 'ps' AND INCLUDE OUTPUT WHEN REPORTING THIS PANIC! IF RUNNING SMP, USE 'mach ddbcpu <#>' AND 'trace' ON OTHER PROCESSORS TOO.
DO NOT EVEN BOTHER REPORTING THIS WITHOUT INCLUDING THAT INFORMATION!
ddb{0}>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The offset is specified in 512-byte sectors.  Your alternative offset of 63 comes from the C/H/S geometry, which is obsolete and should be ignored.

Offset 64 sounds better than 63.  It's clearly more even - it provides alignment to 512*64 = 32KiB.  You *definitely* want to aim for 4KiB alignment.  (Even if you weren't using an SSD - hard drives are now based on 4KiB sectors internally).

Personally I would try aligning to 1MiB.  This would be (1024 * 1024) / 512 = 2048 sectors.

Every other current OS is designed to align to 1MiB.  (I.e. barring bugs).  Sticking to that might avoid weird bugs.  It may also make the partition table easier to understand, when you install other OS's (particularly Linux or Windows), if they use the same alignment as your BSD.  If it's easier to understand it will be easier to spot bugs.  I'm thinking here of a mis-alignment when creating partitions on an existing disk, which I encountered in a previous version of Debian.

Modern flash eraseblocks are much bigger than 32KiB: 128KiB/256KiB at least.  That said I think it mainly matters for RAID purposes.  Because it will only matter for large IOs, and your filesystem isn't necessarily aligned to 1MiB internally anyway.

---

When you said the default offset is 0, this made me concerned.  Sector 0 can't be used for a partition, because it's occupied by the MBR partition table (protective MBR if you're using GPT).  If 0 *was* a valid offset, it would suggest you (BSD) were counting from somewhere else, e.g. just after the MBR, and we'd need to compensate for that.

Your update answers my concern.  Specifying the invalid offset 0 is taken to mean "this partition number is not used".

(It also explains why you described "choosing" which partition(s) to use for your purposes.  I would have instead described "creating" them, because that's how Linux fdisk shows it.  In these respects your BSD fdisk is showing you a more literal view of the underlying partition table format).

Comment: excellent answer! and yes, there's almost no reason at all to be formatting a disk as MBR for any computer made within the past few years - if you're booting in BIOS mode it is only because you have elected to do so as an additional layer atop the firmware's native protected mode. Better to do a GPT format *(I recommend `gdisk` before `GParted` though)* and disable the firmware's compatibility support module.

Comment: @mikeserv OpenBSD expressly cautions against formatting HDD or SSD in GPT format.

Comment: @sourcejedi _However, 0 is also perfectly aligned! I'm completely confused when you say 0 is the default._ Please have a look at my original post to which I added my disk geometry. Following are the results of my second experiment: Using gparted I reformatted my SSD. The partition type is MSDOS. During installation of OpenBSD, I chose 0 to be the partition offset. Once installation was completed, I rebooted my machine and you know what? My machine refused to boot into OpenBSD. All I got was a blank screen.

Comment: @user66229 ty.  That explains the 0. (Ideally I could have guessed from online docs).  The `e` command can also used to 'delete' partitions by resetting them to 0 - it looks like there's no separate delete command.  Offset 0 is invalid because it overlaps the MBR, so I guess the non-zero size is just ignored (by the kernel?).  In that case I think an offset value of 2048, or 64, would be aligned as I wrote in the answer.

Comment: @sourcejedi: Thanks for your suggestion. Which offset value is better: 2048 or 64? and why?

Comment: @user66229 answered already.  I expanded the reasoning when I updated it regarding offset 0.  In this case "everyone else does the exact same thing" is a really good answer.  The only real question is whether there might be reasons to align to a _larger_ number in future, not a smaller one.

Comment: @sourcejedi: Thanks for your detailed explanation. One of these days when I'm a bit free, I shall choose the partition offset at 2048 to see what the effect(s) will be like.

Comment: Comments deleted. Please stay on topic.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, if you run into problems like this a good way how to resolve it is
cat /dev/zero >/dev/disk(whole one) so that it zeroes it all out and then start over with properly aligned disk. It throws sometimes errors when it finds parts of the bootcode that was in there before.

Comment: Could you explain in greater detail on how to use `cat /dev/zero >/dev/disk(whole one)`?